# How to properly unionize indexed type and mapped type

Tags: typescript

I have following example

```
declare type ScopeType = 'work' | 'config';
declare type SelectorData = {
  [Property in ScopeType]: string;
} | { rememberChoice: boolean };

const t: SelectorData = {
  work: "test1",
  config: "test2",
  rememberChoice: true
};


console.log(t.config);
console.log(t.work);
console.log(t.rememberChoice);
```

What I tried to do here, is to force typescript to know that `t` is of type `{work:string,config:string,rememberChoince:boolean}`

This works when I try to create new element, here it is `t` and compiler aseerts that created object matches the `SelectorData`. However, when I try to read properties of `t`, compiler complains

```
Property 'config' does not exist on type 'SelectorData'.
  Property 'config' does not exist on type '{ rememberChoice: boolean; }
```

How can I make it work both ways?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAXAngBwQZTAe3QFTQQF54ByAd2xgGtT4AfMnAOwDMBLAc1IG4AoUJFgIU6eBhARwiKgBEoiKPBIBvPvHgBtAAoxcIGCnjtm4nPkIBdAFzwAzohgnO-AL4N4K+HAC2IHwBGBgDCABbY7GAgtgHY2FJQpq78fCwOSLYSUmAyMPKKyp7q8JQ0tgBEiCAOAIzlADTFLBycFVUOAEwNxb7+QTBhEVG2jgCuIHzJfNNp8SAAdBDYnAAUiPPNXACU-LNSi8tr86XUO6nYzHZzB6vrvYEh4ZEgZ0A

Comment: Simply change `|` to `&` on line 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that

> force typescript to know that `t` is of type `{work:string ,config:string,rememberChoince:boolean}`

So this means instead of union `|` you need intersect `&`!

```
declare type SelectorData = {[Property in ScopeType]: string;} & { rememberChoice: boolean };
```